# Logging event id of an event with GA4 react native to be used to filter for online reports and graphs

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-analytics, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-4

If I want to collect the Event ID when a users views an event to be used for reporting and filtering in GA4, is this code the best way to do it?  The URL has the Event ID, but Id rather have something more precise to grab for online graphs.

```
import { getAnalytics, logEvent } from "firebase/analytics";

const analytics = getAnalytics();
logEvent(analytics, 'event_id', { name: 1});
```